# Is a singleton REST database resource a good idea?

Tags: spring, rest, singleton, jersey, dao

Here's my situation. I have a class called somethingDao that contains all my logic for querying a table.

Then, I also have somethingDaoResource, which is a Jersey API resource, but also a Singleton, and is instantiating a somethingDao object via Spring (i.e., I'm injecting a datasource into somethingDao).

Then, I have a Jersey API businessLogicResource that does:

somethingDaoResource.getInstance().getsomethingDao() which gets me the somethingDao object at which I then fire multiple queries.

My question is, is this considered a good design? My main concern is that every time someone sends a HTTP request to my businessLogicResource, if the somethingDaoResource wasn't a Singleton (or a static?), then that would create a new instance of somethingDao, and open a new connection, which takes a while to do.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

PS - I also have a c3p0 connection pool.

Comment: It seems fine but I'm not sure I comprehend what you're doing. Perhaps some code snippets added to your question would help.

Answer (score 4):

The most common practice is to have DAO objects as stateless singletons. Instead of opening and closing a connection they would borrow one from a pool and then return it when done. You can limit the maximum number of connections in the pool.

Having something statefull and a singleton in a web application is usually a bad idea. It might cause all kinds of read/write conflicts or thread locking. This approach also kills any possibility of distributing your application over a number of servers, which breaks one of the REST architectural constraints.